# Unexplained grid_map cells using RTAB-map

Tags: slam, navigation, rtabmap-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently started using RTAB-map (Debian package) under ROS Indigo and Ubuntu 14.04.  After doing a short mapping run, I bring up localization mode and view the results in RViz.  For the Map display in RViz, I am subscribing to the /rtabmap/grid_map topic and there is an odd semi-circular arc of map cells displayed in the rear half of the plane behind the robot as shown below:

[image: image description]

If I rotate the robot, the arc follows the motion.  If I change the Map topic to /rtabmap/proj_map, the arc goes away and the map looks normal as shown below:

[image: image description]

Any thoughts about what that white arc behind the robot is all about?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/236114/unexplained-grid_map-cells-using-rtab-map/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2016-06-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Patrick,

It seems similar to this issue: https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap_ros/issues/65. This problem affects only /rtabmap/grid_map (which is created from the laser scans).

For now, set `map_negative_poses_ignored` parameter to `true` for `rtabmap` node:

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
    <param name="map_negative_poses_ignored" type="bool" value="true"/>
    (...)
</node>
```

**EDIT**
In `rtabmap_ros` `0.11.7-1` (new version [just released on Kinetic](http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_kinetic_default.html?q=rtabmap)), you can set `flip_scan` parameter to fill unknown cells (the arc) in front of the laser rangefinder instead of behind if mounted upside down or if scan values are taken counterclockwise (you don't have to change `map_negative_poses_ignored`).

```
<node pkg="rtabmap_ros" type="rtabmap" name="rtabmap">
    <param name="flip_scan" type="bool" value="true"/>
    (...)
</node>
```

cheers,

Mathieu

---

Originally posted by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) with karma: 6409 on 2016-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-05**:
Thanks Mathieu.  Unfortunately, when I add that parameter, I stop receiving the map altogether on the /rtabmap/grid_map topic.  But you're right that I have the laser scanner upside down.

**Comment by [matlabbe](https://answers.ros.org/users/20914/matlabbe/) on 2016-06-06**:
The parameter `map_negative_poses_ignored` is affecting the `grid_map`, `cloud_map` and `proj_map` topics the same way. When true, the current sensor data is not added to the map unless the map is updated (when the robot moves). Negative nodes are temporary extra stuff added to maps for convenience.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-06**:
Got it--thanks!

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-12**:
Thanks @matlabbe.  I'm still using Indigo but will keep the new flip_scan parameter in mind for later.